# Postman Running collections against different environments

Tags: environment-variables, postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-collection

I have a postman collection with 3 requests (A,B,C) and I have 3 different environments: "dev", "test", "uat".
I would like to create a Run which will run all 3 requests from the collection against the 3 different envs. So the effective runs will be:

```
env:dev, request A
env:dev, request B
env:dev, request C

env:test, request A
env:test, request B
env:test, request C

env:uat, request A
env:uat, request B
env:uat, request C
```

Is there a simple way to achieve it in Postman?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Newman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/collections/using-newman-cli/command-line-integration-with-newman/) will address your question.

Run newman with environment

```
newman run your.postman_collection.json  -e dev.postman_environment.json
newman run your.postman_collection.json  -e test.postman_environment.json
newman run your.postman_collection.json  -e uat.postman_environment.json
```

Demo REST API

```
https://freetestapi.com/apis/animals
```

Get Animal by [animal name] query
[https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/animals?search=[animal](https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/animals?search=%5Banimal) name]

example

```
https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/animals?search=Lion
```

[image]

#### Set three environments (dev/test/uat)

`dev environment`
[image]

`test environment`
[image]

`uat environment`
[image]

#### Set three requests (dev/test/uat)

`request A`

```
https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/animals?search={{request_A}}
```

`Tests` tab

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
console.log(jsonData[0].name);
pm.expect(jsonData[0].name).to.eql(pm.environment.get("request_A"));
```

Run on `dev' environment
[image]

`request B`

```
https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/animals?search={{request_B}}
```

`Tests` tab

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
console.log(jsonData[0].name);
pm.expect(jsonData[0].name).to.eql(pm.environment.get("request_B"));
```

Run on `dev' environment
[image]

`request C`

```
https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/animals?search={{request_C}}
```

`Tests` tab

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
console.log(jsonData[0].name);
pm.expect(jsonData[0].name).to.eql(pm.environment.get("request_C"));
```

Run on `dev' environment
[image]

##### Export collection and environments

`Export collection`
Will be saved as `1-demo.postman_collection.json`

[image]

`Export environment`
Will be saved as `dev.postman_environment.json`

[image]

Other two environments

Will be saved as `test.postman_environment.json`

Will be saved as `uat.postman_environment.json`

##### Run `newman` with three environments by bash

Save as `run.sh`

```
newman run 1-demo.postman_collection.json  -e dev.postman_environment.json
newman run 1-demo.postman_collection.json  -e test.postman_environment.json
newman run 1-demo.postman_collection.json  -e uat.postman_environment.json
```

##### Run it in git bash

```
./run.sh
```

##### Result

[image]

Comment: I will try it out. Just one question, can I use this without synchronising my collection with postman 'cloud'? I mean I want to have it only localy on my machine and do not want to expose it anywhere else.

Comment: I don't know your new question, you need to make new question with example

Comment: Yes, you can run this completely locally.